# Mysqli query Injection , how to inject the SQL query string?

Tags: php, sql, testing, mysqli, sql-injection

Let's consider i have this line of code

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT  * from myTable where field='".$_GET['var']."');
```

IMHO this is vulnerable to SQL injections.

So I'd like to prove it trying by sending via Get / URL a "var" param that will inject the query, with potential malicious code.

I actually tryed this:

```
var = "1'; TRUNCATE myTable; ";
```

I tryed to print out the SQL string query before executing it and it's actually 2 SQL valid statements.

```
SELECT  * from myTable where field='1'; TRUNCATE myTable;
```

1st problem
But actually itseems that mysqli->query will not execute 2 statements at once. Isn't it?

2nd problem
I see that a common technique to Inject queries is to per form injection then add comment chars to get rid of the tail of the SQL.
Example:

```
"SELECT  * from myTable where field='".$_GET['var']."' AND field2 IS NOT NULL"
```

Can be injected with :

```
var = "1'; TRUNCATE myTable; # ";
```

But this problem arise and I'm missing the trick to get rid of it

if the SQL string in the code have new lines e.g. :

```
    "SELECT  * from myTable where field='".$_GET['var']."' 
     AND field2 IS NOT NULL"
```

If i use the above "var" the final result is

```
 SELECT  * from myTable where field='1'; TRUNCATE myTable; #  
     AND field2 IS NOT NULL
```

Second line won't be commented

How to test injection on this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1st problem But actually it seems that `mysqli->query` will not execute 2
>   statements at once. Isn't it?

That's right, if you want to execute multiple statements you need to use [`mysqli->multi_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php). You can find a good explanation about multiple statements here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

> But this problem arise and I'm missing the trick to get rid of it

The problem arises because you are using multiple statements, and `mysqli->query` does not support them.

About your queries:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT  * from myTable where field='".$_GET['var']."');
```

You can inject this using for example `1' OR 1=1`; that would return all entries of `myTable` on the query result.

```
"SELECT * from myTable where field='".$_GET['var']."' AND field2 IS NOT NULL"
```

Here you could use `1' OR 1=1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE '1'='1`

Nowadays there are tools that can automatically check SQL injection for you, take a look at [SQL Inject Me](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sql-inject-me/) (Firefox Addon) for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, in your opinion, there's not actually a way to inject this code with some destroying approach... (e.g. adding a delete/drop/truncate) but only a spying approach (e.g. select where true | select x | union select all)?

Comment: Yeap, that's how I see it.